# composer require backpack generators exceeded timeout of 300 seconds

Tags: laravel-5, laravel-backpack

I am trying to install backpack for laravel 5.5, using the instructions found on this [page](https://laravel-backpack.readme.io/v3.0/docs/install-on-laravel-55)

I have successfully installed laravel 5.5.

Also I have run

```
composer require backpack/base
```

successfully.

But the problem is when I run `php artisan backpack:base:install`.

I get this error:

[process exceeded timeout 300 seconds](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pnJxb.jpg)

I have tried to follow some solution on this [thread](https://github.com/Laravel-Backpack/Base/issues/217).

I have successfully installed backpack generators separately by running:

```
composer require backpack/generators --dev
```

But I am still getting the same error.

I am running windows 7.

I wonder if there is a way I can install backpack base without backpack generators since I have installed it already.

Any help please would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, you can follow the [manual installation procedure explained here](https://laravel-backpack.readme.io/docs/frequently-asked-questions#section-how-do-i-manually-install-base). Just skip the first step.

```
# Install backpack/generators
composer require backpack/generators --dev

# Install laracasts/generators
composer require laracasts/generators:dev-master --dev

# Publish configs, langs, views and AdminLTE files
php artisan vendor:publish --provider="Backpack\Base\BaseServiceProvider" --tag="minimum"

# Publish config for notifications - prologue/alerts
php artisan vendor:publish --provider="Prologue\Alerts\AlertsServiceProvider"

# Generate users table (using Laravel's default migrations)
php artisan migrate
```